# Getting `java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: HTTP_1_0`

Tags: android, proguard

In my project, I am performing API call using RxJava.
Without proguard, it is running fine. But when I apply proguard It gives `java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: HTTP_1_0`
in `onError(e: Throwable)` of a subscriber.

I applied `-keepclassmembers enum * { *; }` in my proguard to prevent obfuscation.

Api Call

```
 fun latestPosts(): Subscription {
        return service.latestPosts
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(APICallSubscriber(presenterContract, ApiIndex.POSTS))
    }
```

Subscriber

```
class APICallSubscriber<T>(private val callback: BasePresenterContract,
                           private val apiIndex: String) : Subscriber<Response<T>>() {

    override fun onCompleted() {

    }

    override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
        Log.d("HomeTest", "${e}")
    }

    override fun onNext(response: Response<T>) {
        val jsonObject = App.gson().toJsonTree(response).asJsonObject
        val responseCode = jsonObject
                .get(PayloadKeys.RAW_RESPONSE).asJsonObject
                .get(PayloadKeys.CODE).asInt
        Log.d("HomeTest", "$jsonObject")
        val body: JsonElement? = jsonObject.get(PayloadKeys.BODY)
        if (body != null) {
            val responseBody = body.asJsonObject
            callback.onNetworkRequestCompletedWith(responseBody, responseCode, apiIndex)
        } else {
            val errorBody: JsonElement? = jsonObject.get(PayloadKeys.ERROR_BODY)
            callback.onNetwordRequestError(errorBody!!.asJsonObject, apiIndex)
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried different proguard rules but no result.
Please help.

Comment: Have you resolved it ? What a final reason ?

Answer (score 13):

I was facing the same issue, I solved by adding all these in `proguard-rules.pro` file:

```
-keepclassmembers enum * { *; }
-keep class com.google.code.gson.* { *; }
-keepattributes *Annotation*, Signature, Exception
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
  @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}
```

Comment: This is the only combination that worked for me. I wish found your answer 5 hours ago... Thank you!

edit.
Leaving just these two also do the job for me
-keepclassmembers enum * { *; }
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
  @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}

Comment: For me, this fixed it: `-keepclassmembers enum * { *; }`

Comment: Thank you, this helped me to fix my issue

Answer (score 12):

In case this helps anyone, I had an existing project with a library module I had made. To prevent my app from crashing after being minified by ProGuard, I needed to add

```
-keepclassmembers enum * { *; }
```

to not only the library's build.gradle, but also to the main module's build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

below configuration always worked for me

```
-keepclassmembers enum  * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
```

Comment: Its still the same. `java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: HTTP_1_0`

Comment: Api call is not successfull. I am using retrofit2 with rxjava. So i subscribe with a subscriber. Instead of `onNext()` method , it calls `onError(t Throwable)`

Comment: There is not a full stack trace. It's only a line.

Comment: ok , my only suggestion would be too first check what code proguard is generating post obfuscation, you can see the code of class before obfuscation and and after obfuscation , probably progaurd is doing something else which is being unnoticed.  I use Jd gui to see same. you can also use -dontoptimize and
-dontshrink to check